# serverless removes some npm packages while packaging Runtime.ImportModuleError

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am working on an `aws-nodejs` Serverless.js project. When I deploy my lambdas, I started to receive the `Runtime.ImportModuleError` error, indicating that some dependencies are missing. Upon inspection, I found that it is a transitive dependency of my project. In my project, I use an npm package called `graphql-tag`, which has a dependency called `graphql`, which in turn has a dependency called **`iterall`**.

The `Module.ImportError` is occurring due to this **`iterall`** dependency. When I checked it locally, I had this package in my local `node_modules`. However, when I checked the deployed code in Lambda, it simply didn't have this package. Not only this but when comparing my local node_modules to the deployed code, I noticed that only very few dependencies were included in the deployed code.

So, I am a bit confused as I haven't specified anything to include or exclude in `serverless.yml`. Why is it choosing only a few dependencies? Why do the node_modules produced from the `sls package` contain fewer packages compared to the local node_modules? Additionally, **`iterall` isn't a dev dependency** for the `graphql` package.

I checked for GitHub issues and StackOverflow questions, but I didn't find much related to my issue. Can anyone explain this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the package.json contents

Answer (score 0):

There are a few likely causes for this.

The first would be that a custom [Serverless Package](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging) configuration is explicitly excluding that dependency.

The other potential case is that `iterall` is a dependency of some other module, which is listed as a `devDependency` (we'd need to see your `package.json` file to confirm).

Finally, these issues can be compounded by typescript and esbuild/webpack, so you could check those configuration files if that is something you are using.

Any of these could cause the `iterall` package to not be included in the final zip file. Sharing the `package.json` file as well as the relevant snippets of the `serverless.yml` file could help clarify this.

If you remove your node modules entirely, and re-run `npm install --omit=dev`, does the package still appear?